# How can i get a component using xlink:href host bindings to work in angular with ivy enabled

Tags: angular, svg, angular-ivy

I was not able to make a successful plunkr for this so i'm trying to ask this anyways based on description. We have a NG component that uses a host binding to bind an icon property to an svg xlink:href.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'use', // tslint:disable-line
  template: ``
})
export class SohoIconUseComponent {
  // This works but we cant use it because it fails on Safari 12
  // @HostBinding('attr.href') get href(): string {
  //   return '#' + this.icon;
  // }

  // This does not work
  @HostBinding('attr.xlink:href') get xhrefLink(): string {
    return '#' + this.icon; 
  }

  @Input() icon: string;
}
```

So as soon as we upgraded to NG 9 and enabled Ivy our icons stopped working. But if we disable ivy it will work with either href or xlink:href.

Tried looking for bugs in the Ng repo but just cant seem to figure this one out? Any ideas out there?

One idea i have is that you have to use `setAttributeNS` to set the xlink:href sometimes. I wonder if i need to bind the hostbinding a different way so its set using `setAttributeNS`?

Comment: `xlink:href` is deprecated anyway - is there a reason you were using it in the first place?

Comment: The only reason we still need it is that Safari 12 will not load with href yet. We support R-1 browser. The rest of the browsers that needed originally it have expired (or work with href)

Comment: Just found out on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use#Browser_compatibility

href works on 12.2 just not 12.0 (Safari). So that does get us out of the R-1 issue technically.